# Google script. Вызвать скрипт из другого проекта

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Есть отдельный проекта, который по времени выполняет несколько функций. Есть таблица, у который есть свой небольшой скрипт.
**Цель: любой пользователь таблицы может вызвать выполнение функций от моего имени из отдельного проекта, через кастомную менюшку.**
Первым решением было привязать проект как библиотеку, от части, это сработало. Но скрипт выполнялся от имени вызвавшего его и библиотека конфликтовала со скриптом таблицы.
Читал, что надо развернуть проект как приложение. Но не хватает знаний и инфы, чтобы сделать это самому.
Прошу написать простой пример, что надо добавить в таблицу и что в проект. На текущий момент нужно просто вызывать функцию из проекта от моего имени, без передачи данных.
Спасибо.

Comment: Очень скромное объяснение...

Comment: Обожаю людей, которые вместо простой помощи крутят людям яйца. Спасибо за помощь, идите на х*р.

Answer (score 0):

если библиотечная функция работает с текущим контейнером лучше разворачивать как библиотеку, давать доступ клиенту как Читателю.
при этом запуск функции будет производится от лица клиента.
В этом легко убедиться по такому коду:
Клиент:

```
function testLib() {
  librar.myFunction();
}
```

библиотека подключена под идентификатором librar

Библиотека:

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var user = Session.getEffectiveUser();
sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(user.getEmail());
var user = Session.getActiveUser();
sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue(user.getEmail());
}
```

если функция возвращает результат - можно развернуть как веб приложение и в нем указать, что запуск скрипта производится от имени разработчика.

Клиент:

```
  var url = адрес вашей библиотеки;
  var body = {} - параметры, передаваемые в запрос
  var options = {};
  options.method = "POST";
  options.payload = JSON.stringify(body);
    // вызываем метод
    try {
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
      if (response.getResponseCode() < 300) {
        var res = JSON.parse(response);
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
        sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(res.auser);
        sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue(res.euser);
      }
    }
    catch (e) {
      if (logged) Logger.log(e);
      return null;
    }
```

Библиотека:

```
  function doPost(e) {
    var euser = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
    var auser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"active": auser,"effective": euser}))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```